# solving ODE using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm preparing for my final and came across a problem in the practice set which our professor didn't post the answers to... I tried to solve this question but failed to integrate $u_1'$ and $u_2'$. Here is the ODE: $$y''+y'-2y=\ln(x)$$

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: It seems the integrals aren't elementary... [Here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%2By%27-2y%3Dln+x) WA's solution.

Comment: First find the solution to the corresponding homogeneous equation $y\prime\prime+y\prime-2y=0$ by using characteristic equation $r^2+r-2=0$

Answer (score 1):

Having found two solutions of homogeneous equation, $u_1(x)=e^{-2x}$ and $u_2(x)=e^{x}$, and computed the Wronskian $W=3e^{-x}$, we end up with general solution $u=Au_1+Bu_2$ where 
$$A=-\int \frac{u_2}{W} \ln(x)\,dx = -\frac13 \int e^{2x}\ln x\,dx$$
$$B=\int \frac{u_1}{W} \ln(x)\,dx = -\frac13 \int e^{-2x}\ln x\,dx$$
All we can do with these is integrate by parts (differentiating $\ln$), which expresses both integrals in terms of [Exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\mathrm{Ei}$. I doubt that this was professor's intent, though.